# Why is secrecy of correspondence treated differently than telephone or electronic surveillance

Tags: communications-law

According to wikipedia ["secrecy of correspondence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secrecy_of_correspondence) "Paper letters have, in most jurisdictions, remained outside the legal scope of law enforcement surveillance, even in cases of "reasonable searches and seizures". "

Why is communication with letters treated differently than communication by other means?

Comment: Historical development, and the difference in intercepting a physical object vs. listening to communications. A letter *can* usually be overtly seized with a search warrant, while a phone call can only be covertly tapped.

Comment: @o.m. Looks like an answer in a comment to me. Please don't do that.

Comment: @quarague, it is completely lacking in sources, which means it is not really an answer, either. Should I delete it?

Comment: You may, but should not, because someone else might be inspired by the comment and write a proper answer. It is a helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

### They aren’t treated differently

In most jurisdictions, law enforcement requires a warrant to intercept/open/read the contents of physical or electronic correspondence.

Similarly, in most jurisdictions, a warrant is *not* required to read the metadata: who is communicating with whom, how and when but not *what*. That is they can read what’s written on the outside of the envelope or the routing information of the email/SMS.

Telephony is *not* correspondence because it is not the intent of the parties to create a permanent record. It is usually treated as any other conversation - if it carried out in a place and manner that the participants have a reasonable expectation of privacy it’s usually illegal to record it (electronically or by writing it down). If it’s said publicly, it isn’t illegal.

Comment: You state that they aren't treated differently while wikipedia stattes that they are.